# Hiding a user's posts in a followed feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm just getting started understanding Stream, so bear with me.

Here's my scenario: I want to have feeds for different music genres that a user can follow, and activities in those feeds would be collected from various artists' feeds.  It appears the right way to do this is target the genre feeds, when an artist posts on their own feed.

Say my user's timeline feed is following "genre:indie" feed, and "genre:indie" receives posts from "artist:radiohead" and "artist:the-national".

If the user wants to hide posts from just "artist:radiohead", while still following "genre:indie", is there an easy way to filter them out?  Or would I have to do this server-side, after querying Stream API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, Nick here from Stream. At this time we don't have support for filtering; however, it is in our long-term roadmap. For now, the best way to do it would be on the server after you query the Stream API. Thanks for choosing Stream and happy coding!